# SQL relations between blog and author

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

heya I am new to SQL thing
I am trying to make a Blog 
the plan goes like 
a single blog can have only one AUTHOR
where a Author can have more than one blog
and a single blog can have multiple images

can any one make me understand how will the relation go with this for the sql mapping??

Comment: I forget to tell something 
A Blog will have multiple images and visa verse
That is a single image can also be used in multiple blogs...
Then how will I set the relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create table Author
(
Id int
, Name nvarchar(max)
);

Create table Image
(
Id int
,ImagePath nvarchar(max)
);

Create table Blog
(
Id int
,Name nvarchar(max)
,AuthorId int
);

Create table BlogImages
(
Id int
,BlogId int
,ImageId int
);

ALTER TABLE Blog
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId)
REFERENCES Author(Id);

ALTER TABLE BlogImages
ADD FOREIGN KEY (BlogId)
REFERENCES Blog(Id);

ALTER TABLE BlogImages
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ImageId)
REFERENCES Image(Id);
```

In above relation we have a table `BlogImages` having `blogId` and `ImageId` , which means single `imageID` can have multiple `blogIds` , so multiple blogs using the same image which satisfies your requirement

Comment: I forget to tell something 
A Blog will have multiple images and visa verse
That is a single image can also be used in multiple blogs...
Then how will I set the relations?

Comment: We have given in above structure ImageId maps to BlogId in separate table.. so single image can be stored with multiple blogIds ,so satisfies your requirement. single image can be used in multiple blogs also

Comment: But is possible to enter 2 foreign keys in a single table ???U have entered 2 foreign keys in a single table BlogImage has 2 foreign keys..
IS IT RIGHT??

Comment: Yes we can have more than one foreign key per table. the only constraint is we can only one primary key per table.

Comment: Thanx sir.. But then what will be the query to fetch total number of images in a blog?
....And query for total number of images per user?..?

Comment: You mean total count ??

Comment: declare @blogId int
,@authorId int


select
i.Id
,i.ImagePath
,bi.BlogId
from
[BlogImages] as bi
inner join [Image] as i
on bi.ImageId=i.Id
where
bi.BlogId=@blogId

select
i.Id
,i.ImagePath
,bi.BlogId
,b.AuthorId
from
[Blog] as b
inner join [BlogImages] as bi
on b.Id=bi.BlogId
inner join [Image] as i
on bi.ImageId=i.Id
where
b.AuthorId=@authorId

Comment: In above first query is images per blog, and the second one is images per author..

Comment: can u please guide me with a proper query..I am confused

Comment: declare @blogId int


select
i.Id
,i.ImagePath
,bi.BlogId
from
[BlogImages] as bi
inner join [Image] as i
on bi.ImageId=i.Id
where
bi.BlogId=@blogId

The above query will fetch images for given blog Id

Comment: select
i.Id
,i.ImagePath
,bi.BlogId
,b.AuthorId
from
[Blog] as b
inner join [BlogImages] as bi
on b.Id=bi.BlogId
inner join [Image] as i
on bi.ImageId=i.Id
where
b.AuthorId=@authorId.. the query will fetch images for given user

Comment: but I have not declared any kind of inner joint...
Is it necessary to do it..
Can u please guide with a query without inner joint.

Answer (score 1):

> Author ----> Blogs -------> Images..

So let me explain the plan a little bit.

There will be a table authors having all details of authors. PK being author_id.
Blog table will be having details of blogs. Blog_id being the PK and will be having a foreign key author_id referenced by author table.
Image table will be having details of images. image_id being the pk and will be having a foreign key blog_id referenced by blog table.

The behaviour is known as [one to many relation](https://www.google.com/search?q=one%20to%20many%20relation%20in%20sql&oq=one%20to%20many%20relation%20in%20sql&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j5j0l2j69i62l2.7767j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=one%20to%20many%20relation&oq=one%20to%20many%20relation&gs_l=serp.3...5160.5160.0.5330.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.ka8K-yFx9ek&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.bmk,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=bed81e6b5f71ca88&biw=1280&bih=923)

Comment: I mean a single blog can have single author..but a single author can have multiple blogs..so what type of relation will it be?

Answer (score 0):

Set up an author table with an ID. In your Blog table use a unique ID for the blog, and include the author ID as a column, Finally, in your images table, include the blog ID, and perhaps the author ID. You should get something like this:

```
Author id -------------> Blog Id -------------->Image ID
Other Author details     AuthorID               Blog Id
                         Other Blog details     Author ID
                                                Other Image data
```

With this you can use SQL Join on Author ID or Blog Id to get the data in the next table.